# How to pull code based up one or another condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Let's say we have two tables A and B. Both tables have `From` dates .i.e. `A.FromDate` and `B.FromDate` and both can be joined on `MemberID`. I need to pull a list of members from table  with following condition on `From Date`

`FromDate` should be calculated:

- If `A.FromDate` is less than `B.FromDate`, use the `B.FromDate`
- If `A.FromDate` is equal to or greater than current group span `B.FromDate`, use the eligibility span `A.FromDate`
- If dates cannot be determined, member should be included on an exception list.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*,
       CASE WHEN A.FromDate  < B.FromDate THEN CAST(B.FromDate AS VARCHAR(15))
            WHEN A.FromDate >= B.FromDate THEN CAST(A.FromDate AS VARCHAR(15))
            ELSE 'Exception' END AS FromDate
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.MemberID = B.MemberID
```

The `ELSE` condition would only fire when the inequality between the dates cannot be determined, which would happen when one or both of the from dates be `NULL`.